# Validation messages in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to implement knockout validation. For this example I have Vacancy typed object with observable property in it. Everything works except displaying error message near input in UI (jquery pop up window) if I leave the empty input. What should be my next step?

JS

```
    ko.validation.configure({
                        registerExtenders: true,
                        messagesOnModified: true,
                        insertMessages: true,
                        parseInputAttributes: true,
                        messageTemplate: null
                    }

    var Vacancy = function() {
                    this.Header = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
    }

    function viewModel() {
         self.selectedVacancy = ko.observable(new Vacancy());

         self.action= function() {
                self.validationModel = ko.validatedObservable({
                        P1: self.selectedVacancy().Header
                });
                        if (self.validationModel.isValid()) {
                            alert('Do Action');
                        } else {
                            alert('Not Valid');
                        }
    }
```

UI

```
<label>Header: </label>
<input data-bind="value: Header"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Validated Observables have a showAllMessages method that you can use to manual show messages. Instead of, or in addition to, opening the alert you can call showAllMessages like so:

```
self.validationModel.errors.showAllMessages();
```

Also, make sure the [insertMessages](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) configuration option is set to true, that's the default but you may have changed it when you initialize

Comment: Great! If you think that answer solved you problem, I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer.